# Can't insert a user input value because "str object has no attribute get" in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So several other people have asked similar questions, but I don't think they necessarily apply to my situation. I'm writing a program that's eventually going to take user inputs, check to make sure they correct, and then save it all to a file. Currently, I'm passing all the user inputs to a text box in tkinter so that I can just save whatever's in that one text box. I'm using a for loop to go through the 7 user entry fields I have and then insert them into the text box.

```
def submit(self):
    """ submits user data up to input data section of GUI and checks USL vs LSL"""
    e6 = IntVar(self.e6)
    e7 = IntVar(self.e7)

    if e6 > e7:
        message = "Limits are good"
    else:
        message = "USL can't be less than LSL, please re-enter USL and LSL"

    self.checklimits.delete(0.0, END)
    self.checklimits.insert(0.0, message)


    x = 1
    for x in range (1, 8):
       xname = "self.e" + str(x)
       entry = xname.get()
       if entry:
            self.checktext.insert(END, entry + "\n")
       x = x+1
```

I'm wanting to take the x value in the for loop and eventually end up with something like "self.e#.get()" since that's how i've defined the user entries, see example below:

```
 def create_widgets(self):
    """create widgets for user inputted data"""      
    # creates a text widget next to the entries that displays what the user has input
    Label(self, text = "Do these values you entered seem correct?").grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.checktext = Text(self, width =15, height = 42, wrap = WORD)
    self.checktext.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 10, column = 4, sticky = W, padx =5, pady =5)

    # get name
    Label(self, text = "First Name:").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e1 = Entry(self)
    self.e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)       
    Label(self, text = "Last Name:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e2 = Entry(self)
    self.e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Right now though, python isn't recognizing that entry as an entry and is saying back to me that "'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

So for one, why can't I "get" a string value, and two, how can I get python to recognize my previously defined entry? Here's my entire code for context

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
""" A SPC program that takes user input and saves the file """
def __init__(self,master):
    """ initializes the frame """
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()     

def create_widgets(self):
    """create widgets for user inputted data"""      
    # creates a text widget next to the entries that displays what the user  has input
    Label(self, text = "Do these values you entered seem correct?").grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    self.checktext = Text(self, width =15, height = 42, wrap = WORD)
    self.checktext.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 10, column = 4, sticky = W, padx =5, pady =5)

    # get name
    Label(self, text = "First Name:").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e1 = Entry(self)
    self.e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)       
    Label(self, text = "Last Name:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e2 = Entry(self)
    self.e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    # get work order
    Label(self, text = "Work Order Number:").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e3 = Entry(self)
    self.e3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    # get todays date
    Label(self, text = "Todays Date:").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e4 = Entry(self)
    self.e4.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    # get bubble number
    Label(self, text = "Bubble Number:").grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e5 = Entry(self)
    self.e5.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    # get USL and LSL
    Label(self, text = "USL:").grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)        
    self.e6 = Entry(self)
    self.e6.grid(row = 5, column = 1)    
    Label(self, text = "LSL:").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)       
    self.e7 = Entry(self)
    self.e7.grid(row = 6, column = 1)                       

    """# button to check USL is higher than LSL
    self.button7 = Button(self)
    self.button7["text"] = "Check Limits"
    self.button7["command"] = self.check_limits
    self.button7.grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)"""

    # button to submit user entered values up to the input data values portion of the gui
    self.button6 = Button(self)
    self.button6["text"] = "Submit"
    self.button6["command"] = self.submit
    self.button6.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)

    # creates a spot to dictate whether USL and LSL are correct
    self.checklimits = Text(self, width = 20, height = 2, wrap = WORD)
    self.checklimits.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = W, padx = 5)

    """ #adds a scroll bar to the data input text box
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y) """

    # get User Input Data values
    Label(self, text = "Enter Results:").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W, padx=5, pady=5)        
    self.e8 = Text(self, width = 15, height = 30)
    self.e8.grid(row = 7, column = 1)     

    """ def check_limits(self):
    checks to see if the USL is greater than the LSL 

    e6 = IntVar(self.e6)
    e7 = IntVar(self.e7)

    if e6 > e7:
        message = "Limits are good"
    else:
        message = "USL can't be less than LSL, please re-enter USL and LSL"

    self.checklimits.delete(0.0, END)
    self.checklimits.insert(0.0, message)"""

def submit(self):
    """ submits user data up to input data section of GUI and checks USL vs LSL"""
    e6 = IntVar(self.e6)
    e7 = IntVar(self.e7)

    if e6 > e7:
        message = "Limits are good"
    else:
        message = "USL can't be less than LSL, please re-enter USL and LSL"

    self.checklimits.delete(0.0, END)
    self.checklimits.insert(0.0, message)


    x = 1
    for x in range (1, 8):
       xname = "self.e" + str(x)
       entry = xname.get()
       if entry:
            self.checktext.insert(END, entry + "\n")
       x = x+1                              

root = Tk()
root.title("SPC Input Program")
root.geometry("700x750")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't make variables with names like that.  Use a list or dictionary instead.

Comment: use `eval(xname)` instead of `xname.get()` although Kevin suggestion is even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are assuming that `e6 = IntVar(self.e6)` is getting the value of an entry widget and converting it to an int. That's not what it's doing. It is creating a new variable named `e6` that is initialized to zero, and has `self.e6` as the "master".

If you want to get the values from an entry widget and convert it to an integer, use the `get` method on the entry widget.

```
e6 = int(self.e6.get())
e7 = int(self.e7.get())
```

The problem that is causing the "str object has no method get" is this code:

```
xname = "self.e" + str(x)
entry = xname.get()
```

This is a terrible way to code. As you can see, it won't work. You can make it work with tricks, but a good rule of thumb is to never try to dynamically create variables like this.

If you want to loop over the entry widgets, put them in a list or tuple. For example:

```
for widget in (self.e1, self.e2, self.e3, self.e4,
              self.e5, self.e6, self.e7, self.e8):
    entry = widget.get()
   if entry:
       self.checktext.insert(END, entry + "\n")
   ...
```

Comment: While you're at it, refactor `self.e#` into `self.e[#]`.  Then you can loop over `self.e` directly.

Comment: So what @Bryan Oakley submitted worked, but I like the idea of storing the entries into an array instead. So how would I do that exactly, @Kevin? I tried doing it like this:                                                            `for x in self.e:
           entry = x.get()
           if entry:
                self.checktext.delete(0.0, END)
                self.checktext.insert(END, entry + "\n")` but that only passes the last entry, not all of them

Comment: @jvaille: Wherever you set those `self.e#` variables (in the `__init__()` function?), you need to change that to creating a list or dictionary and populating it.

Comment: @Kevin: is that not what im doing with this line of code `self.entry_list = [None]*7` ? I put that in the `__init__()` function at the top of my code

Comment: @jvaille: That creates a list called `self.entry_list`.  If you want to do things with a list called `self.e`, you will need to create it first.  Also, please keep in mind that Python lists start counting from zero.  If you need to start counting from one, you'll want a dictionary instead.

Comment: @Kevin: sorry for the confusion. I had changed my code to reflect some of  y'all's suggestions previously, so now I have `self.entry_list = [None]*7` in the `__init__()` function, and have changed all the previously `self.e#`'s to be `self.entry_list[#]`, so the names are correct in the for loop and throughout the body of the code. So now that for loop looks like `for x in self.entry_list:` as opposed to `for x in self.e`. But still the problem remains, whenever I run the code that for loop only passes the last entry

Comment: @jvaille: It sounds as if you only indented the `entry = x.get()` line, and not the rest of the loop.  Since this depends on indentation, it *cannot* be reasonably resolved in the comments.  Please ask a new question.

Comment: @Kevin: alright, I will. Thanks for the help though!